# I have a method that requires a path as a String to get a file, how do I do it?

Tags: android

I have am porting to Android a Java class which contains a method like this

```
new AdaptivePaymentsService(
                "src/main/resources/sdk_config.properties");
```

I have the **sdk_config.properties** file, how can I pass it as file path to the  method?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following path: `classpath:/sdk_config.properties`
It should work if it comes to a packaged archive.

Comment: Do you have a null object or some exception when serving src/main/resources/sdk_config.poperties as a file path?

Comment: Try simply `new AdaptivePaymentsService("sdk_config.properties");`